# Insert into another table with trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, insert

I want to insert a record after insert with trigger, but it doesn't work properly.
it's on an accounting table.
First I wrote the trigger and I got this error:
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint The conflict occurred in database The statement has been terminated.
Then I found the key and wrote the trigger on that table and then I got new error:
this sqltransaction has completed it is no longer usable sql server
and here is the trigger:

```
USE [Sepidar01]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Alter TRIGGER [INV].[CrmSelectInsertVWInvoiceItems] 
ON  [INV].[InventoryDeliveryItem] 
After Insert
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CustomerCode varchar(40)
DECLARE @InvoiceRef INT
DECLARE @Price decimal(19, 4)
DECLARE @CreationDate datetime
DECLARE @Quantity decimal(19, 4)
DECLARE @GuID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @KalaCode int
DECLARE @BaseInvoiceItem int

SELECT @BaseInvoiceItem=(BaseInvoiceItem) FROM INSERTED

select @CreationDate AS [inv.CreationDate],@CustomerCode AS [dl.Code],@Price       
AS [invitem.Price],@Quantity AS [invitem.Quantity], @KalaCode AS [itemst.ItemStockID]
from [Sepidar01].[INV].[InventoryDeliveryItem] as invent
join sls.InvoiceItem as invitem
on BaseInvoiceItem =InvoiceItemID
join sls.Invoice as inv
on InvoiceId = InvoiceRef
join acc.dl as dl
on inv.CustomerRealName like dl.Title
join inv.ItemStock as itemst
on invitem.ItemRef = itemst.ItemRef
where invent.BaseInvoiceItem  = @BaseInvoiceItem

SELECT @GuID AS [bartar_newpaitientId]
  FROM [192.168.0.15].[Bartar_MSCRM].[dbo].[bartar_newpaitientBase] as newPatient
  where newPatient.bartar_CustomerCode = @CustomerCode

INSERT INTO [192.168.0.15].[Test_MSCRM].[dbo].[bartar_callcenterreportBase]
       ([bartar_callcenterreportId]
       ,[OwnerId]
       ,[statecode]
       ,[CreatedOn]
       ,[bartar_Date] 
       ,[bartar_patientName]
       ,[bartar_Brand]
       ,[bartar_Paste]
       ,[bartar_Bag]
       ,[bartar_ACC]
       ,[bartar_NextDateSales]
       ,[bartar_name])
 VALUES
       (NEWID(),'315BE87D-0035-E511-80B5-0007E9498006',0,@CreationDate,@CreationDate,@GuID,0,0,0,0,@CreationDate,'System')

END
```

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Tag dbms used, to get better attention! (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.)

Comment: And I used it on view as instead of insert, Neither gives any error, nor inserts any data

Comment: Your trigger is broken. It assumes exactly one row in `inserted`. In fact, there can be 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. Prefer to write a single `INSERT ... SELECT` statement that references `inserted` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ِYou must change your first select like this:

```
select @CreationDate=[inv.CreationDate],@CustomerCode=[dl.Code],
@Price=[invitem.Price],
@Quantity=[invitem.Quantity], @KalaCode=[itemst.ItemStockID]
from [Sepidar01].[INV].[InventoryDeliveryItem] as invent
join sls.InvoiceItem as invitem
on BaseInvoiceItem =InvoiceItemID
join sls.Invoice as inv
on InvoiceId = InvoiceRef
join acc.dl as dl
on inv.CustomerRealName like dl.Title
join inv.ItemStock as itemst
on invitem.ItemRef = itemst.ItemRef
where invent.BaseInvoiceItem  = @BaseInvoiceItem
```

And the second one:

```
SELECT @GuID=[bartar_newpaitientId]
  FROM [192.168.0.15].[Bartar_MSCRM].[dbo].[bartar_newpaitientBase]
    as newPatient
  where newPatient.bartar_CustomerCode = @CustomerCode
```

So your vars get value.

And if you get this error `Msdtc on server is unavailable`, this is the solution:
[fix error](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/03/24/sql-server-fix-error-8501-msdtc-on-server-is-unavailable-changed-database-context-to-publisherdatabase/)